# Click on a href link in an already opened browser window

Tags: html, vbscript, qtp, browser-automation

In the below code I'm trying to click on the "About" link (`href`) in the www.google.co.in website. This worked on IE11 (Windows 10), but is not working for IE10 (Windows 7).  Is this in anyway machine dependent. If not what is the right code?

Please remember I'm trying to click on a link in an already opened browser window.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    'You can use my_title of my_url, whichever you want
    If my_title Like "Google" & "*" Then   'identify the existing web page
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

Dim LinkHref
Dim a

LinkHref = "//www.google.co.in/intl/en/about.html?fg=1"

For Each a In ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")
  If LCase(a.GetAttribute("href")) = LCase(LinkHref) Then
    a.Click
    Exit For  ''# to stop after the first hit
  End If
Next
```

Comment: If you are using QTP, perhaps it would be simpler to use the built in browser automation with some descriptive programming, or even just use the object repository to learn your target site and navigate it?  The best approach will depend on your overall goal for the script though

Comment: What is the __Like__ in `If my_title Like "Google" & "*" Then` ?

Comment: strange....But it does work as i said on my Win10 IE11 browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the goal with descriptive programming in QTP (if you don't want to use the object repository for some reason).  This code should give you an example of what you can do:

```
Dim oDesc ' create a Description object for objects of class Link
Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc("micclass").value = "Link"

'Find all the Links in the browser using ChildObjects
Set obj = Browser("title=Google").Page("title=Google").ChildObjects(oDesc) 

Dim i
'obj.Count value has the number of links in the page
For i = 0 to obj.Count - 1   ' indexed from zero, so use 0 to Count -1
   'get the name of all the links in the page           
    If obj(i).GetROProperty("innerhtml")= LinkHref Then 
        obj(i).Click 'click the link if it matched the href you specfied
        Exit For ' no need to carry on the loop if we found the right link
    End If 
Next
```

If you just need to use vbscript, you can do it like this:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oWindow
For Each oWindow In oShell.Windows
    If InStr(oWindow.FullName, "iexplore") > 0 Then 
        If InStr(1, oWindow.Document.Title, "Google", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set ieApp = oWindow
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

LinkHref = "//www.google.co.in/intl/en/about.html?fg=1"

For Each linky In ieApp.Document.GetElementsbyTagName("a")
    If LCase(linky.GetAttribute("href")) = LCase(LinkHref) Then
        linky.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

This is pretty much the answer given above by Ansgar, but with a little extra to fix the object error.  Only a browser window has the `Document.Title`, and the loop is working through every window that's open, so you get the error when the loop tries a non IE window.  This version fixes that by only checking for the `Document.Title` if the window has been identified as an IE instance in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Dave for ur answer but could this be done in vbscript alone?

Comment: I've added a vbscript only method to my answer for you

Comment: I think this is not finding the ie window...coz it says object required for "ieApp"

Comment: If that's on the `For Each linky` line then yes, the code hasn't found an IE window with an open Google tab.  I've tested this locally on the google.co.in site and it does work; do you have the browser open, on Google's page?

Comment: You may need to add in some debug statements to check what the script is doing.  After the `For Each oWindow` line add Wscript.echo `oWindow.Fullname` and the script will list the name of each window as it sees it.  This will let you check if it does actually find the IE window.  Add `Wscript.echo oWindow.Document.Title` after the `If InStr(oWindow.FullName, "iexplore") > 0 Then` line and it will tell you all the titles it sees.  This will help you figure out what is being seen and also then not seen...

Comment: Got it. The name of the explorer was IEXPLORE and not iexplore!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about QTP, but VBScript doesn't have a `Like` operator.

This is the usual way to attach to an IE window with a specific title in plain VBScript:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each wnd In app.Windows
  If wnd.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
    If InStr(1, wnd.Document.Title, "Google", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      Set ie = wnd
      Exit For
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: @Ansar Wiechers It says 'Object doesn't support this property or method' "wnd.Document.Title"

Comment: You probably have (file) Explorer windows open as well. See updated answer.